# Prevent Context Menu click when there are no options

Tags: jquery, contextmenu

I have a context menu where I am showing options based on fields that have been populated.  The context is on the same page as the fields so if they put content in a text box I want that to show immediately in the context menu.  All of this works.

This is a page where we are defining flags that can be inserted into text fields/areas in other sections of the program via context menu.  One of the fields that uses these flags is on the same page.

My issue is if none of the fields are populated.  When right clicking for the context menu I get a javascript error saying there are no items defined.  Is there any way to stop the context menu from firing when empty?

```
$.contextMenu({
    selector: '.context',
    trigger: 'right',
    build: function($trigger, e){
        var options = {
            callback: function(key, options){
                switch(key){
                    case "Field1":
                    //Code
                    break;
                    //More Options
                }
            },
            items: {}
        }
        if($('#Field1').val() != ""){
            options.items['Field1'] = { name: $('#Field1').val(), icon: "Field1" }
        }
        //More Fields
        return options;
    }
});
```

Comment: From the documentation: _the build callback may return a boolean false to signal contextMenu to not display a context menu_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a variable to track whether you added any items to the menu. Then you can return `false` if none were added.

```
build: function($trigger, e){
    var showMenu = false;
    var options = {
        callback: function(key, options){
            switch(key){
                case "Field1":
                //Code
                break;
                //More Options
            }
        },
        items: {}
    }
    if($('#Field1').val() != ""){
        options.items['Field1'] = { name: $('#Field1').val(), icon: "Field1" };
        showMenu = true;
    }
    //More Fields
    return showMenu && options;
}
```